# WPF playing gif in MediaElement not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf

> I want to play Gif and I am using MediaElemnt but unfortunately it's
>   not working... when I play gif I stop after some frame and it stops
>   after 5-7 seconds... it's working for small duration GIF but when I
>   used gif around 10-second duration its stop after 5-7 seconds...

```
<MediaElement Name="elementGif" MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="400" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Manual"  Grid.Row="0"  MinWidth="50" MinHeight="50" MediaEnded="elementGif_MediaEnded">
    <MediaElement.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=sharebrder, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </MediaElement.OpacityMask>
    <MediaElement.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity=".2" Color="#FF29ABE2"/>
    </MediaElement.Effect>
</MediaElement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a library for showing a GIF animation in WPF. I have used a library called "XamlAnimatedGif" in the past and it's a good library for showing Gif animation and it's also up-to-date. There Github page is:

https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif

Or search for a nugett package called "XamlAnimatedGif".

Comment: i already used this.. there is handle leak and high memory usage if I play 3-4 gif parallelly ...

Comment: Are you sure you used "XamlAnimatedGif" library and not "WpfAnimatedGif" library? the owner has improved the new "XamlAnimatedGif" library specifically to tackle the high memory usage problem.